# Echoing json object writes invalid JSON on IIS only

Tags: php, iis

I have the following php web service that writes text (a json object).
This text is then parsed as JSON in javascript code.

```
$comments = new Attachments();
log(json_encode($comments->toArray()); // log prints correct JSON object
echo json_encode($comments->toArray());
```

The JSON built is correct, the log is correct.
However, on IIS 6.2 only, the JSON object is invalid, eg:

The JSON object as logged is :

```
{"someObject": 42, "someOther": "43", "aaa": "bbb", "someKey": "bbb" }
```

The JSON object as sent by IIS is :

```
{"someObject": 42, "someOther": "43", "aaa": "bbb", "someKey": "bbb" }eKey: "bbb" }
```

The JSON sent contains a repetition of the end of the json, which produces invalid JSON.

This bug happens 80% of the times.

Do you have any idea on what could be the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was due to VPN issue.

There is no issue if I access the same website with its external URL, outside of our VPN.